# Get table Name , column Name and the number of rowcount of each column in sql

Tags: sql-server

Can you please help me with a SQL Query , I want to find all tables name ,column names and total number of rows count of each columns for all tables in all databases. Is there a query that can do that for me. Please refer the below example

I want the below result.

```
TableName ColumnName  TotalRowCount
TABLEA    A            10
TABLEA    B            20
TABLEA    C            17
TABLEA    D            20
TABLEB    X            60
TABLEB    Y            45
TABLEB    Z            67
```

Regards

```
I have tried this....

SELECT
      QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) AS [TableName]
      , SUM(sPTN.Rows) AS [RowCount]
FROM
      sys.objects AS sOBJ
      INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS sPTN
            ON sOBJ.object_id = sPTN.object_id
WHERE
      sOBJ.type = 'U'
      AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
      AND index_id < 2 -- 0:Heap, 1:Clustered
GROUP BY
      sOBJ.schema_id
      , sOBJ.name
ORDER BY [TableName]
​
```

Comment: Why you will have different number of rows count for same table ? Are you counting not null by column ?

Comment: @AnandKumar, I don't think we can help until you answer the question Squirrel asked. Add clarity about how TotalRowCount can vary by column.

Comment: Columns don't have a row count, *tables* do. If a table has 1,000 rows then *every column* in the table has 1000 rows too. You can't have some rows that don't have a column. For example, you can't do `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ID = 1` and get the columns `Col1`, `Col2`, and `Col3`, and then do `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ID = 2` and only get `Col1` and `Col2`.